# Alternate entry activity for Android app

Tags: android, android-activity

When a user first runs my app, I need them to run through a brief setup/tutorial set of Activities.

How can I set up my app to open the SetUpActivity on first run instead of my MainActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a Launcher activity to open any activity after a logic is performed, for example if the user has opened the app for the first time and it doesnt have any registration data or whatsoever you can send him to the Intro and then if the app is opened after the Intro is executed (you can save some Variable in the preferences), you can redirect them to another activity like Main or something, I do that in an application i have running and I think some others do that same thing also (like Telegram).

Here is an example of what i mean.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.company.app" >
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activity.Launcher"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
              android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.telegram.messenger.android.profile"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="telegram.me" android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="telegram.me" android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tg" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

This in the example will also catch any Intent for sharing images and text, then in your launcher you can open the activity with the action you want to perform from those share intents.

Then from that Launcher activity you can have something like this...

```
package com.company.app.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by eefret on 23/12/14.
 */
public class Launcher extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // be sure to get your preference accordingly
    if(somePreference == true){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);


    }
}
```

That way you can have a flexible start for your app in any case you want... You can check Telegram github repo also for their running example. Hope it help you.

Answer (score 3):

A simple edit to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file will do the trick:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityToStart"
        android:label="@string/activity_helmet_remote_name"
        android:theme="@style/themeLight">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlternateActivity1"
        android:theme="@style/themeLight">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlternateActivity2"
        android:theme="@style/themeLight">
    </activity>
</application>
```

As you can see in the example above, `ActivityToStart` will open when the application is launched since it has the `android.intent.action.MAIN` label. Simply move that label to the activity that you want to start when the application opens. If you wanted `AlternativeActivity1` to start when you open the application then your `AndroidManifest.xml` file would look like the following:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityToStart"
        android:label="@string/activity_helmet_remote_name"
        android:theme="@style/themeLight">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlternateActivity1"
        android:theme="@style/themeLight">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlternateActivity2"
        android:theme="@style/themeLight">
    </activity>
</application>
```

You also want to make sure to move the `LAUNCHER` line...

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

to the `Activity` you wish to start upon opening the application, as this is used to register the default `Activity` with the Android launcher.

On the other hand, if you wish to launch an `Activity` only once, `SharedPreferences` would be the way to go. `SharedPreferences` allow you to save values that can be accessed globally within your application. An easy way to do it would be to set up a simple `Activty`, which you start everytime, that checks whether the tutorial should be started or whether your main `Activity` should be started. Something like the following:

```
public class StartupActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        /** Create the Activity */
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startup_activity);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (!sharedPreferences.contains("firstLaunch"))
        {
            // Add SharedPreferences key ("firstLaunch")
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("firstLaunch", 1);
            editor.commit();

            // Launch tutorial Activity here...
        }
        else
        {
            // "firstLaunch" preference exists, which means application has been launched before
            // Launch primary activity here...
        }
}
```

The above `Activity` will, everytime the application is launched, check to see if a `SharedPreference` entitled `firstLaunch` exists. If it does **NOT**, that means that the application has never been launched before, and the `firstLaunch` key is created and added to the `SharedPrefernces`; this is also where you want to launch your tutorial `Activity` from. On the other hand, if the `firstLaunch` `SharedPreference` does exist, that means that the application has been launched before, so you simply start your standard `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't think you understand the question. I only want to modify the entry point on the first run, so that I can run a setup screen. Your solution changes the entry point for EVERY app run.

Comment: I understand. I have amended my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not inherit from `android.app.Application` and decide which `Activity` to show during `onCreate()`.

**Note**: You should also change your `manifest.xml` `android:name` tag to `.MyAppplication`.

Somthing like this:

Extend `Application`:

```
public class MyAppplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Get value from data store
        boolean showTutorial = true;

        if (showTutorial) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Update your `manifest.xml`:

```
 <application
    android:name=".MyAppplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon64"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".screens.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Note**: The usage of the `android:name=".MyAppplication"`.

Comment: can you explain how I can choose which Activity to start by overriding onCreate() in the overriding Application class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences to achieve this. Just declare your SetupActivity the default activity in your manifest. Then on your onCreate method, check if one var inside SharedPreferences has been initialized, and if that is the case create an Intent to your MainActivity.

If it hasn't been initialized go on with the Setup process, and once it's finished initialize the var in your SharedPreferences.